# Jquery .next() function not working

Tags: jquery

Guys i am trying to do something like this i have two href and a text box in the middle of those <-> TEXT <+> So when i press the - and + the value in the txt must increase or decrease by one

and i am using a jquery to + and - the value in the text box. Whenever i press + its happening correctly but for - it takes the TEXT fields name instead of its value . Any solution for this to make it to take the value of the TEXT box Jquery used follows :

```
$(".quantity .subtract").click(function () {
    var qtyInput = $(this).next('input');
    var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
    if (qty > 1)
        qtyInput.val(qty - 1);

    qtyInput.focus();
    return false;
});

$(".quantity .add").click(function () {
    var qtyInput = $(this).prev('input');
    var qty = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
    if (qty >= 0 && (qty + 1 <= 999))
        qtyInput.val(qty + 1);

    qtyInput.focus();
    return false;
});
```

And their Ids ll be different as more than one time i m using thm in the page

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code in the question. Edit your question, then highlight your entire block of code, then hit the ctrl+shift+k (or the toolbar button that looks like a pair of curly braces: `{ }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have did something lik this it worked out.
got all the next for the  tag for that

```
var qtyInput = $(this).nextAll('a');
var qtytxt = $(qtyInput).prev('input');
var qty = qtytxt.val();

if (qty > 1)
    qtytxt.val(qty - 1);

qtytxt.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

`next` finds an element after the element you are calling `next` upon. Instead using `siblings`:

```
var qtyInput = $(this).siblings('input');
```